# В чём разница между Array и new Array?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, в чем разница между кодом `var a = Array(10)` и `var a = new Array(10)`, и почему оба варианта работают одинаково?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827008/4928642

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`new` создаёт новый объект (инстанс класса) и передаёт его вызываемой функции в качестве `this`. Но некоторые функции умеют сами определять, что их вызвали без `new` и всё равно отрабатывать как конструктор. `Array` - одна из них, поэтому разницы нет.

Если хочется самому создать подобный конструктор, то вот один из способов:

```
function Smth(val) {
  if (!(this instanceof Smth)) {
    return new Smth(val);
  }

  this.val = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для данного случая разницы нет, как я понимаю. Вообще, `new` - вызывает конструктор указанного объекта. Потому, при создании экземпляров объектов (а вы это и делаете) надо его использовать. Подробности [здесь](http://javascript.ru/new), [здесь](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance), и [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes). Задавай вы значение литералом (например, `var a = []`), вызов конструктора был бы не нужен, но это не значит, что он не сработал бы.

Comment: Для переменной вообще нет разницы, что в неё присваивают. Ответ непонятен.

Comment: _"Все переменные, в JS, - те же объекты"_ - а как же примитивы?

Comment: Любое присваивание - обычное.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм, я не припомню не одной переменной, у которой не было бы методов. Но возможно я что-то упускаю. Пойду погуглю.

Comment: Методы есть у всего. Как бы есть. Но у примитивов они только из прототипа - им нельзя добавлять свойства. А у объектов-обёрток они есть. `var a = 5, b = Number(5), c = new Number(5);
a.x = 12, b.x = 12, c.x = 12;
console.log(a.x, b.x, c.x);` результат `undefined undefined 12`. А в строгом режиме вообще исключение `VM669:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'x' on number '5'`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, да, вы правы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы удалил ответ, но ваши комментарии терять неохота. Может, перенесёте их в свой?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36847/discussion-between-risto-and-qwertiy).